# Flutter: dynamically editing images

Tags: flutter, image, animation, video

im looking into trying to create something like the following in flutter:

https://youtube.com/shorts/ZL7YsY9jTjg?feature=share

I know its silly, but im interested to see if this is possible to do in flutter. The idea is that you would pass in properties like user names and imageUrl’s, and create something like the linked video.

The more concrete part of this question is, how can i dynamically rotate images like the linked video? Each image in the video starts at a certain zoom or rotation, and ends at a different point. Is implementing something like this in flutter possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can freely animate/rotate/scale any Widget with Transform in a Stack.

```dart
Transform.rotate(
  angle: -math.pi / 12.0,
  child: // any widget... like Images
),
```

There are also animated versions of these Transform widgets where you can animate rotation and scale in between two values over a certain time.

Lookup implicit and explicit animation in Flutter.